# How to do auto scroll to particular header location in separated list view?

Tags: iphone, ios, listview

I am working on  separated List view in my app,And headers are classified by dates , And my
  requirement is , By the time activity opens the listview must automatically scroll to the particular
  header position ,in my case the listview must scroll to the header with  current date.

In the below view thursday,july 4th is currentdate so list automatically scrolled to current date by the activity starts .
  My view should be seen as [image: In the below view thursday,july 4th is currentdate so list automatically scrolled to currentdate .]

Comment: This is not related to Android development. Please use proper tags in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need
[smoothScrollToPosition(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition%28int%29).

Comment: i to no that but how to get that position in seperatedlistview is my question

Comment: You probably have a data structure that holds the data that you load. The list view loads from it as the data is arranged. Search for the item you need and its position is the position to scroll to.